# CSS "if wrap then fit-width children"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I am trying to achieve without javascript is to have four buttons arranged in a 2x2 matrix as long as all of their content fits into a cell. When any of them is too long to fit, it should wrap into a 1x4 matrix, with all the cells being having full width. The best I could come up with for now is something like the snippet below. It is just fine until the point where after the wrap the cells should have full width.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

.flex-item {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 2em;">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container" style="width: 150px; margin-top: 2em;">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div
```

Comment: That's a super use-case for css grid!

Comment: @Lux, I have no doubts, I tried that too, but I could not manage it to work either. Actually, I was unable to make it wrap at all without media queries. If you could share a solution, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? I made `flex:1;` for `.flex-item`

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

.flex-item {
    flex:1;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 2em;">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container" style="width: 150px; margin-top: 2em;">
  <div class="flex-item">AAA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">BBBBBB</div>
  <div class="flex-item">CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div class="flex-item">DDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div
```

Comment: more precesily it's `flex-grow:1` and you can get rid of all the alignment properties, they are useless